# Using Imperial unit of slugs for mass in R units package

Tags: r, unit-testing, package, units-of-measurement

I am writing R code that is flexible with units, either SI or Imperial (which I call US). I am having difficulty with density (mass/volume) in Imperial units using the *units* package.

```
library(units)
#check to see if units are in database
ud_units["slug"]
```

which returns NULL. Slug is a defined unit in the [UDUNITS2](https://ncics.org/portfolio/other-resources/udunits2/) database with a equivalence of 14.59390 kg, so maybe I missed something. But the units package allows a new variable so I tried to define a new unit:

```
install_symbolic_unit("slug")
```

which returns a warning that "‘slug’ is already a valid unit recognized by udunits". A fresh restart allows me to try using the unit of slug.

```
x <- set_units(5, slug/ft^3)
set_units(x, kg/m^3)
```

which returns "Error: cannot convert slug/ft^3 into kg/m^3". This leaves me confused as to why a valid unit of mass cannot be converted to another valid unit of mass. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Works for me: `2576.894 [kg/m^3]` if you don't `install_symbolic_unit("slug")`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Edward. I opened up a new console with a cleared environment, re-ran library(units) but I guess my experiment with install_symbolic_units persisted. I uninstalled the units package and re-installed it and now it works correctly, as you show.

Comment: What's weird is that the "slug" unit doesn't appear in the list returned by `ud_units`. Yet the command works perfectly.